# can't use last Express version

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to update to the last Express version in my project, but seems to be impossible.

Last stable version is 4.13.4:

[image]

If I run `npm list express -g` to check my global version installed, I have:

```
$ npm list express -g
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- express@4.13.4
```

But if I run `npm express -v`, the output is:
    3.8.3

If I open `package.json`, it has:

```
//...
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^0.7.7",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "escape-html": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jade": "*",
    "method-override": "^2.3.5",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.8",
    "node-mysql": "^0.4.2",
    "node-oauth2-server": "^2.0.2"
},
//...
```

No matter if I run `npm install` or `npm install express@4.13.4`, output for `npm express -v` is `3.8.3`.

Could be possible that other module is forcing to not update Express to 4.*? How could I confirm that?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `npm list express-generator -g` show? That is the module that provides the `express` CLI.

Comment: `$ npm list express-generator -g

    C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm

   -- express-generator@4.13.1`

Comment: I've checked that is the last stable version

Comment: In your app folder go into node_modules/express and open package.json what is the version in there?

Comment: `
args: "express@4.13.4"
"_from": "express@4.13.4"
"_id": "express@4.13.4"
`